# Converter file section is null

Tags: c#

I'm making a BRRES to BFRES converter. For some reason, the MDL0 section seems to be always null when debugging. Here is the code for the Brres file loader:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a set of properties controlling the load of a <see cref="Brres.BrresFile"/>.
/// </summary>
internal class BrresLoaderContext
{
    // ---- CONSTRUCTORS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BrresLoaderContext"/> class for the given <see cref="BrresFile"/>
    /// instance using the given <see cref="BinaryDataReader"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="BrresFile">The <see cref="BrresFile"/> instance to load the data in.</param>
    /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="BinaryDataReader"/> to use for reading the data.</param>
    internal BrresLoaderContext(BrresFile brresFile, BinaryDataReader reader)
    {
        BrresFile = brresFile;
        Reader = reader;
        Warnings = new List<string>();
    }

    // ---- PROPERTIES ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="BrresFile"/> instance which is loaded to.
    /// </summary>
    internal BrresFile BrresFile
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="BinaryDataReader"/> which is used to read data from the input stream.
    /// </summary>
    internal BinaryDataReader Reader
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the warnings raised after loading the Brres file.
    /// </summary>
    internal List<string> Warnings
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

I mostly didn't update comments.

So why is it null?

Comment: this code should work, please share the code that erros

Comment: What is the _MDL0  secttion_ that you say is null?

Comment: Well, this is the loader, so there is nothing else that loads BRRES files in the entire solution.

Comment: A section of the BRRES file.

Comment: @iSYan - Please show the use of this class because this class is ok. You say you get nulls - where is the code that in it you get the nulls?

Comment: Here is the solution: http://www.4shared.com/zip/rp3B3qhEba/BRRES2BFRES.html?

Comment: Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you

Comment: It is used to load the BRRES file.